# Replace the generated TOC.yml by custom TOC.yml

Tags: yaml, navigationbar, tableofcontents, docfx

I'm using docfx to generate API documentation for my .Net project.
I need different flavors of what can be shown to different customer types.
When generating the metadata, the TOC.YML is generated as well, which is fine. 
However when the generating the html files, this TOC is used to create the navigation bar at the side of each HTML page. 
The problem is that for a certain audience, the full side bar should not be available and should only show the navication which is provided by the customize toc.yml. 
I can create a new custom TOC in a custom folder and navigate to the pages, but when an html page is loaded it (of course) displays the navigation bar of the complete generated TOC.yml.

Reading the doucmentation.
Created own TOC file (which is working) but I don't find the option where the custom TOC.yml is used iso of the generated one.
Tried to exclude the toc.yml in the docfx.json.

```
{
    "metadata": [
        {
          "src": [
            {
              "files": [
                  "LIB/myassembly.dll"                  
                ],
            "include": [""],
            "exclude": [
              "**/toc.yml"
            ],
            "cwd": "../output/Debug/"
            },
            {
                "files": [
                    "**.cs"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                ],
                "cwd": "../../../TestScripting/Scripts"
            }
        ],
        "dest": "api",    
        "force": true
        }
    ],
    "build": {
        "content": [{
                "files": [
                    "api/**.yml"
                    ]
            },
            {
                "files": [
                    "scripting/index.md",
                    "scripting/toc.yml",
                    "articles/**.md",
                    "articles/**/toc.yml",
                    "toc.yml",
                    "*.md"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                    "obj/**",
                    "_site/**"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "resource": [{
            "files": [
                "images/**"
            ],
            "exclude": [
                "obj/**",
                "_site/**"
            ]
        }],
        "overwrite": [{
            "files": [
                "apidoc/**.md"
            ],
            "exclude": [
                "obj/**",
                "_site/**"
            ]
        }],
        "dest": "../Doc",
        "globalMetadataFiles": [],
        "fileMetadataFiles": [],
        "template": [
            "default","darkfx/darkfx"
        ],
        "postProcessors": [],
        "noLangKeyword": false,
        "keepFileLink": false,
        "cleanupCacheHistory": false
    }
}
```

The expected result is: 
The navigation bar displayed by each generated html file should be based upon the custom toc.yml.